# Can we update fiscal year settings using apex code?

Tags: apex

I have a situation in that suppose one condition is satisfied then a month let say 'April' is set as Fiscal Year Start Month, otherwise 'Jan' is set. I have to do this by apex code, not from the setup|administration|company profile. 
Can we do so by using apex code?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [SFDC Objects doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm), SObject `FiscalyearSettings` is not creatable, updateable, or deleteable

```
describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve()
```

nor for that matter is `Period`

```
describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve()
```

While it is true that there are some sobjects that can't be updated via DML in APEX, but can be updated via REST API. However, these two Sobjects are not in that set.  As you can imagine, changing these could cause havoc on an org

Comment: How SF would update settings/ records of these objects from SF administration page? Could you please share some info or links for that?

Comment: @user2275344 - this is all covered here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_define_cfy.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @crop1645- with that we can create custom fiscal year, but after creating custom fiscal year, we can not update fiscal settings. What I want: Is there any way to update fiscal year settings object for updating fiscal year settings conditionally? As SF updates fiscal year settings from administration|company profile. Since FisaclYearSettings soject is not updatable, So how SF would update that settings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to do this via Apex API.

If you have to absolutely need to do this somehow, then one possible way is to simulate the POST http data that Salesforce UI sends to server when user changes the value. Note that this is a hack and it may break anytime.